# Writing to HBase using Pyspark too slow - row by row?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hbase

I want to write a dataframe using Pyspark into HBase, so I am using the below code:

```
properties = {
        "hbase.zookeeper.quorum": "my_quorum",
        "hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort": "my_port"
 }
```

```
df.write.format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark").options(
    catalog=schema, table=name_of_table
).options(**properties).save()
```

I have set properly so the schema of the dataframe as the properties.
Moreover, the process of writing is done but is too slow and I wonder why. I have thought that the method .save() writes to HBase row by row, is that right?

Thank you in advance.